# MySQL - Use min function or limit an order-by query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit, min

I am writing a query to find the product with the **minimum** price. 
These are the two queries I tried:

```
select min(price) from products
```

and

```
select price from products order by price limit 1
```

The first one returns **19.950000762939453** and the second one returns **19.95** which is the accurate value. So my question is, what's the difference of the two queries?, why is the first one weird?! and which has a better performance for this task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data type of  `price` is probably a floating-point with is by definition inaccurate.

If you use a fixed-point data type like `decimal` it will be `19.95`.

You can read it up [in the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-types.html)

Comment: I checked, yes the type is Float. So which of the two queries do you think would be faster?

Comment: See for yourself with  `explain select ...`.

Answer (score 1):

min has better performance, according strange values - you should read how [floating numbers are stored in memory/db](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754%3a_floating_point_in_modern_computers), they are "rounded"

if you store real price - go with [DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html) type, it will work fine